# Is there any documentation on NVCC compiler optimization heuristics?

Tags: cuda, nvcc

I'm looking for detailed documentation about NVCC compiler choices to optimize the code. But so far I haven't been able to find anything interesting in Nvidia documents nor in literature.

Comment: No there isn't....

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no documentation, official or otherwise, describing the compiler internals.

You might be able to infer some basics if you:

1. You can look at the official documentation at,

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-gpu-code-generation

In particular, you need to be aware of the HW details of the GPU you are targeting, including registers, memory, if you decide to play around with the flags.

2. The instruction set reference would be helpful, and can be found at,

https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/index.html#instruction-set-ref

3. Unofficially, lot of analysis has been going on in academia, for ex, for characterising latencies,

https://www.groundai.com/project/instructions-latencies-characterization-for-nvidia-gpgpus/1

4. ***cuobjdump*** utility can be useful for analysing the generated code, as discussed in (sass is also described there)

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-sass-code-analysis/41167

Comment: How does any of this answer the yes/no question "Is there any documentation on NVCC compiler optimization heuristics?"

Comment: While you are right about the question's title, in the description the OP states " ..documentation about NVCC compiler choices to optimize the code", and hence makes it more general, including optimisation flags.